# Can I smuggle a shield on me when I'm infiltrating a place?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, stealth, shield

I'm working on a zealot vigilante whose primary role is to be a face/infiltrator with combat being a secondary focus, just enough to be a viable threat. I settled on a simple sword and boarder, but the thing is I'm not 100% if I can hide a shield on me. My gut is telling me I could get away with a buckler, but I just wanted to make sure.

If not, I'll probably have to settle for a single weapon build.

Comment: Voting to reopen - the other question is about weapons larger than light, while a light shield IS a light weapon and can clearly be concealed using the Sleight of Hand skill rules.

Comment: Do you specifically want to know about the object-hiding rules, or are you interested in alternative solutions like a Glove of Storing (but presumably less expensive)?

Comment: I know plenty of magical ways to do it, but i'd like to try to avoid relying on that if i can.

Comment: Since its possible to "smuggle" a large pizza into a movie, then a shield should be possible as well

Answer (score 1):

[Light shields are light martial melee weapons](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/) and can [be hidden on your person using the Hide Object action under the Sleight of Hand skill](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/sleight-of-hand/#hide_object).

It seems a little unrealistic to me, personally, I'd expect some kind of penalty beyond the +4 someone frisking you gets, but by the rules, it works.  Some other weapons just in the core rulebook alone that you might not expect to be able to hide but can include: punching dagger, light mace, sickle, light pick, *spiked armor*, light spiked shield, starknife, 2-foot-long shortswords with basket hilts...